# How do I add events to nested server controls? (ASP.Net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling

I am building a custom master page type control i.e. sort of like a datagrid but should be easier to add custom functionality into it. It's going great but part of the desired functionality is to have a paging control that switches on and off and part of that control would be a textbox that displays the current page number and on TextChanged redirects to the new page of the dataset.

The problem I'm having is that technically the textbox which has its event fired is embedded in a control that is embedded in the control you actually put on the page sort of like

Page
  |
Display Control
   |
Paging Control
   |
Textbox

Buried all the way down there the event is not firing. Worse the postback javascript isn't even being written onto the page (Nothing on the page posts back so far this is the only bit that really needs to).

I've been trawling around Google for quite a while now and picked up that I need to implement INamingContainer (done) and I need to add the control into the page's control tree (is Pre_Init too late for that? When's a good time to Add the Control to the page?) then the event should fire, apparently. But I've been unable to find an example of best practice on this there are quite a few near misses where people are having button angst but this isn't a button.

So can anyone point me in the direction of getting a control embedded in a control embedded in a control added to a page to behave properly?

Comment: Not sure the complete answer, just wanted to address two parts: init is OK to add controls; pre_init may be too early; secondly, events typically need to bubble up, like when you click a button in a gridview, and that click event bubble's up to the grid to fire an appropriate event; RaiseBubbleEvent is the method that bubbles up an event.  Seems like the TextBox doesn't bubble up the changed event...

Comment: That's it... bubbling events. Yes. Now how would one do this bearing in mind that I have made all thus far suggested changes and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was a combination of the above answer and the comment on the original question. The vital thing to get the event to happen is to make sure that your controls (parent and child) inherit from CompositeControl and INamingContainer e.g.

```
public partial myControl:CompositeControl,INamingContainer
etc...
```

Then you override your composite control's CreateChildControls() method and create your controls and do the wire up there. This will ensure correct bubbling. and mean that the event handling takes place within your comoposite control...

Answer (score 0):

You need INamingContainer only if you plan to add more than one instance of your custom control to the same page. What it does is enabling unique id generation so you don't end up with controls with the same ID. I recommend you inherit from [CompositeControl](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/01/29/436854.aspx) when creating your custom control. 
Pre_Init is not too late. Actually it is pretty early considering the lifecycle. You can instantiate custom controls and add them to the live controls collection in a lot of places. I would recommend you do it in Page_Init (before viewstate is loaded) or Page_Load(after view state is loaded). Even if you add it later in the page lifecycle the control will catch up in events.
To subscribe to events of child controls you can use the FindControl method:

```
MyControl myControl = Page.FindControl("MyControl1");
TextBox textBox = myControl.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
```

Comment: This is all very well and I see where you're coming from but it is essential that the textchanged event resides in the paging control, not in the resident page. So subscribing to the event from the top level page isn't going to help me. It's more the bubbling thing that Brian talks about in his comment. Thanks though.